# How to retrieve a list of the current user's blogs using Blogger API?

Tags: java, android, rest, google-api, blogger

I am currently trying to get a list of a user's blogs in Android with Blogger API, specifically, the current user's blogs. I have the OAuth2 token linked with the account that's logged in, using the methods in this tutorial [Authorizing Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth).

The Blogger API documentation says that I can make a request to fetch the list with `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/userId/blogs`
, and that I can replace `userID` with `self` if provided the OAuth2 token as the Authorization header, as it describes:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs
>
> Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */

So I made a `JsonObjectRequest` using Volley:

```
    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            tv.setText("Response is: " + response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", mToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

The `MySingleton` class is copied from [Setting Up a Request Queue](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html):

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

After executing this code, it gives me a 401 error saying that I am not logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So careless of me. The `Authorization` header is formatted wrong! It should be `Bearer *token*` not just `*token*`.